Crystal radio antenna question
I am trying to make crystal radio.
I have almost everything I need (magnet wire, high impedance headphones, germanium diode.) The only thing I am missing is the antenna.
I know that if I want to receive the AM band I need to have about 60m (197') of antena (530+1170/2) to wavelength = 267/4 = my antenna length.
The problem is I don't know how thick the wire should be because the thicker the wire is, the more expensive it becomes and it is harder to store and manipulate.
I am also not sure what capacitor would I need. I know that high impedance headphones (not piezo electric ones) need some capacitor but I am not sure what value and what type. I have a 50V 1uF electrolytic one, a CBB28 metallized polypropylene film one, and what looks to be a tantalum one (green SPMZ8) at hand.

What is the capacitor used for, how do you intend to connect it?

Birds are at risk of wire thinner than AWG #26 magnet wire, And single-strand copper is at risk of work-hardening in the wind or from kinking during installation. Hey, don't forget about ground connection - it is an important part of the antenna system. Your question would benefit from a circuit diagram - (there are many variations). We are unsure of where you intend to install that capacitor.

schematic is just simple antena: tunning coil, germanium diode, headphones (and capacitor probably goes in series before the headphones): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Circuit_diagram_of_a_crystal_radio_receiver.svg/1200px-Circuit_diagram_of_a_crystal_radio_receiver.svg.png  the installation is intended to be portable (install it when use, and maybe mount it on a kite or use electric fence (not connected) as antena


I know that if I want to receive AM band I need to have about 60m
(197') of antenna (530+1170/2) to wavelength = 267/4 = my antenna
length

You don't need this length of antenna. In fact trying to make it a quarter wavelength long will be counter productive to tuning because it presents a resistive impedance and you can't get the tuning to work. So, let me start by saying that you should consider an antenna that is less than half that length.
The AM band is nominally 1 MHz and, that has a wavelength of 300 metres so, I'd go for a 30 m antenna and, you might find that 15 metres will do pretty good too.
This ensures that the antenna presents a capacitive impedance to the tuning coil. Here's an image that indicates the impedance presented by the antenna at various frequencies. The original image source is at the top and my additions are the obvious coloured boxes, numbers and lines: -

The additions I made to the above were to show what impedance was presented by the antenna when it was nominally designed to be a quarter wave long at 2.5 MHz (30 metres in length).
At an operating frequency of 1 MHz the antenna will present an impedance of about 300 pF and, that will help you get good selective tuning.

I don't know how thick the wire should be because the thicker the wire is, the more expensive it becomes and it is harder to store and
manipulate.

1 mm diameter internal conductor will be fine. It can also be regular hook-up wire with an insulating sheath.

I am also not sure what capacitor would I need

The capacitor after the diode detector will be much smaller that 1 μF for sure. Probably in the order of a nano farad but, try it without and see what happens.

oh ok, so I guess thickness does not matter with radio operation

@LaCalienta not when operated at these small powers and making use of it being a so-called "short" antenna. A short antenna means operated significantly below the quarter wave point. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

@LaCalienta you don't appear to have accepted my answer. Is there a reason for this?

sorry, totaly forgot to do that :)
